# Dynamic variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I have a question about dynamic variables. (I have trouble searching because I have a hard time describing my problem)

In this example:

```
$x = 1;
$var = "A$x";
echo $var;    //prints 'A1'
```

Now my question is, is there a way to combine "computation" without adding another variable?

What I want to do is:

```
$x = 1;
$var = "A($x+1)";
echo $var;    //I want to output to be 'A2' but it gives 'A(1+1)'
```

I know that this works:

```
$var = "A".($x+1)
```

But this is not applicable to the program that I am doing. `$var` is initiated on the beginning of the program and will be used at the end waiting for any value of `$x`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to concatenate your output.

```
$x = 1;
$var = "A". ($x + 1);
echo $var;
```

In your example the "+1" is inside the quotes and thus is a literal string.

Comment: When a question has been answered hundreds of times, vote to close instead of answering for some rep.

Comment: Fair enough chief ;)